# ActiveMQ Storage full is not freeing up when consumer starts( not recovering)

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a producer and a consumer that communicate through ActiveMQ. I stopped the consumer and want to exceed the storage limit but when the consumer starts consuming, to drain all the stale messages. I would like to **recover**.

```
   <policyEntry memoryLimit="5 mb">
   <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="5 mb" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="5 mb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="5 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>
```

I receive the following error in console:

Usage(default:store:queue://queue:store) percentUsage=99%, usage=5312120, limit=5242880, percentUsageMinDelta=1%;Parent:Usage(default:store) percentUsage=101%, usage=5312120, limit=5242880, percentUsageMinDelta=1%: Persistent store is Full, 100% of 5242880. Stopping producer (ID:ROC01-LT1071-62775-1518528229890-1:1:1:1) to prevent flooding queue://eueue. See http://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control.html for more info (blocking for: 1147s)

I have stopped the consumer and then ***after*** I restart the consumer, the consumer does not consume the staled messages.

How can ActiveMQ be configured so that when the consumer is started it starts reworking.

Comment: Did you try enabling JMX for the broker http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html to spot any anomalies upon reconnect?

Comment: Yes, but I have not seen any anomalies. I have space on the disk. Do you know if I could programmatically connect to JMX and modify the some attributes ?

Comment: You could check if the queue has any messages before your consumer connects.

Comment: There are messages that were not processed. I am wondering if there is way of recovering

Comment: I'm afraid at this point it is hard to understand where the problem is. Can you share some code, e.g. consumer part?